# ORDER BY not working with raw SQL Query in Symfony2, but works on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a query that returns a list of dates I use for a drop down date picker, here is the SQL query.

```
SELECT `completion_date`
FROM `enviro_figures_upload`
GROUP BY YEAR( completion_date ) , MONTH( completion_date ) 
ORDER BY YEAR( completion_date ) ASC , MONTH( completion_date ) ASC
```

Through phpMyAdmin, the query returns the results I need in the order I need:

```
2014-01-01
2014-02-01
2014-11-01
2014-12-01
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
```

In my Symfony2 application, here is the code I use to get this data to my application:

```
    $sql4 = "SELECT `completion_date` FROM `enviro_figures_upload` GROUP BY YEAR(completion_date), MONTH(completion_date) ORDER BY YEAR(completion_date) ASC, MONTH(completion_date) ASC;";

    $activeDateSelect = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql4);
    $activeDateSelect->execute();

    $activeDate = $activeDateSelect->fetchAll();
```

However, the results aren't in the correct order at all. The results that are returned are like this:

```
2014-01-01
2015-01-01
2014-11-01
2014-12-01
2015-02-01
```

I can't understand why the results are being changed like this. What can I do?

**EDIT**
The field type where the date is VARCHAR not DATE. This is because the client I'm building this for can't change the format of the date in Excel which he uses to create the CSV. So the date is uploaded in the UK format, at which point I then reformat the date to the current one.

Here is a var_dump of the `fetchAll()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-01-06
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-02-06
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-03-06
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-04-06
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-05-06
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-06-06
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-07-06
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-08-06
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-09-05
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-10-05
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-11-05
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2014-12-05
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2015-01-01
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2015-02-01
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [completion_date] => 2015-03-01
        )

)
```

**EDIT 2**
I iterate the results through Twig like this:

```
{% for ad in actdate %}
     <option value="{{ad.completion_date|date('Y-m')}}">{{ad.completion_date|date('F Y')}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: We're assuming that the datatype of the `completion_date` column is `DATE`, and the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions are returning integer values. There's no reason that the `ORDER BY` clause shouldn't be passed to MySQL, or why MySQL wouldn't honor that. Can you do a vardump of $activeDate after the fetchAll()? (We're expecting an array of arrays, `Array ( [0] => Array ( [completion_date] => `. (What we're not seeing is how you are retrieving the values from the array.) (I don't think the semicolon is required within the `$sql4` SQL text.)

Comment: I copied your code letter for letter, ran it on one of my tables that has a datetime field and it works perfectly via doctrine. As @spencer7593 suggests, do a dump of $activeDate. I would expect it to be ordered correctly and the ordering to be an issue in your code somewhere.

Comment: Added more information including the var_dump.

Comment: That array looks ordered correctly. How are you iterating out the results?

Comment: I've added the Twig code to the question. Starting to suspect the way Symfony2 is running the query is the problem here.

Comment: Are you manipulating actdate at all before using it in twig? If you're not that array should print in the exact same order you pasted. It's not the query if the array you pasted as generated by fetchAll is correct, and that looks correctly ordered to me.

Comment: The only bit of manipulation that occurs is when I pass the `$activeDate` array to the view. So I use the code `'actdate' => $activeDate` when creating the view.